# Pyupdater Client.refresh() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyupdater

When I try to create a client from Pyupdater, I get the following error. I also created and imported the keys since the error seems to point that *_get_signing_key()* is **None**.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 65, in
>
> ```
> status = CheckForUpdates()   File "setup.py", line 31, in CheckForUpdates
>
> client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyupdater\client\__init__.py", line 213, in __init__
>
> self.refresh()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyupdater\client\__init__.py", line 217, in refresh
>
> self._get_signing_key()   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyupdater\client\__init__.py", line 368, in _get_signing_key
>
> key_data = json.loads(key_data_str.decode("utf-8"))   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
>
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
>
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
>
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> ```

This is the following code.

```py
import sys
from client_config import ClientConfig
from pyupdater.client import Client
from progressbar import ProgressBar, Percentage, Bar
import warnings
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os

BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

__version__ = "1.0"
bar = None


def CheckForUpdates():
    """
    Check for updates.
    Channel options are stable, beta & alpha
    Patches are only created & applied on the stable channel
    """
    def cb(status):
        global bar

        if bar is None:
            bar = ProgressBar(widgets=[Percentage(), Bar()], fd=sys.stdout).start()
        zz = float(status['percent_complete'])

        bar.update(zz)
    
    CLIENT_CFG = ClientConfig()
    client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True)
    
    print("Current Version: ",__version__)
    #logger.info('Checkung for updates')
    appUpdate = client.update_check(CLIENT_CFG.APP_NAME,
                                    __version__,
                                    channel='stable') # alpha, beta
    
    print("Checking for updates...")
    if appUpdate:
        if appUpdate.latest > appUpdate.current_version:
            check = input("New Update available. Do you want to install the update?(y/n)")
        if hasattr(sys, "frozen") and check=="y":
            appUpdate.progress_hooks.append(cb)
            downloaded = appUpdate.download()
            if downloaded:
                check = input("Do you want to restart the application now?(y/n)")
                if check == "y":
                    status = 'Extracting update and restarting.'
                    appUpdate.extract_restart()
                else:
                    status = 'Update download failed. Try again later'
            else:
                status = 'Update download failed. Try again later'
        elif check=="n":
            status = 'Update download failed. Try again later'
        else:
            status = f'Update available with version {appUpdate.version} but application is not frozen.'
    else:
        status = 'No available updates were found.'

    return status
```

Pyupdater and pyinstaller versions:

> python==3.7.9
>
> pip==22.1
>
> Pyupdater==4.0
>
> pyinstaller==5.1

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69493633, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69469717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyUpdater 4.0 is broken. See [PyUpdater issue 320](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater/issues/320).

Some options:

- downgrade to PyUpdater 3.1.1.
- wait until [PR 322](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater/pull/322) is accepted (or install directly from the fork)
- wait for [PyUpdater 5.x](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater/issues/320)
- try an alternative, e.g. our [tufup](https://github.com/dennisvang/tufup) (TUF-updater)

### Update:

Its seems PyUpdater is now [officially archived](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater/blob/main/README.md?plain=1#L1), so there won't be any new releases there.

Comment: The alternative looks neat. Although I have stopped using auto-update for different reasons, I will get back on this if I get the need.