# How to use PyUpdater with updates from USB flash drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyupdater

I am trying to use PyUpdater without an update server, but updates from flash drives instead. Any ideas on how to instantiate the class `AppUpdate` without the `Client.check_update()` method?

Comment: Note that PyUpdater 4.0 is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73192339) in many ways, and the project is now officially [archived](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater#this-is-the-end), i.e. it is no longer maintained.

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to update from a flash drive? Any reason you couldn't just run an installer directly from that drive?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that *"without an update server"* refers to an actual *online* (production) server:

A quick workaround would be to serve the files locally from the usb drive, e.g. using python's [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server):

`python -m http.server -d <path to folder on usb drive>`

Then you would need to point your app to the corresponding url path on `localhost`, by adding the url to the `UPDATE_URLS` in your  `ClientConfig`:

```py
class ClientConfig(object):
    PUBLIC_KEY = 'abcdefg...'
    APP_NAME = 'my-app'
    COMPANY_NAME = 'my-company'
    HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30
    MAX_DOWNLOAD_RETRIES = 3
    UPDATE_URLS = [
        'http://localhost:8000/my_updates/', # <<<<<<<<<< this one
        'https://example.com/my_updates', 
        ...
    ]
```